Why does evaluating enviroment variable in setting.py does not work?
I set an environment variable here
~/.bashrc

by adding
export DJANGO_DEVELOPMENT=true

the committing the changes with
source ~/.bashrc

Then I checked if the value was correctly wrote with
echo $DJANGO_DEVELOPMENT
-->RESULT: true

Now I'm simply triyng to accede this variabile during the server launch, so Django can figure out I'm in development and override the settings.py file with a settings_dev.py file.
The code doing this in setting.py is:
import os

if os.getenv('DJANGO_DEVELOPMENT') == 'true':
    from .settings_dev import * 

The problem is that the server is always executed with
DEBUG = False

so I know as a fact that python is not reading properly the env. variable.
I also double checked by putting a
print(os.getenv('DJANGO_DEVELOPMENT'))

but it's always None.
Someone have any idea where my error is?

You did not show, how you are calling your Python program, but did you ensure that you have set the environment variable in that process as well? Show your "server launch script".

Sure, when I launch the server my script is just "./manage.py runserver".

source ~/.bashrc will directly affect only the specific shell process in which it is run.  The modified ~/.bashrc will be accessed directly by some other shells that you start after making the modifications.  Other shells that were already running will not see the changes, and new login shells might or might not do so. To avoid confusion around which shells are affected and which not, (1) ensure that ~/.bash_profile reads ~/.bashrc, and (2) log out and back in.

@HackZero: Great, but what kind of shell is your processing your script? If it is an interactive non-login bash shell, it sources .bashrc automatically. Otherwise, you are responsible for explicitly setting hup the environment.
